# Работа с сокетами Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет

У меня есть скрипт на Python с реализацией клиентского сокета, которые считывает данные с серверного сокета.

```
class Client:
    sock_client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    GoWork = False
    def __init__(self, IpAddr, port):
        self.IpAddr = IpAddr
        self.port = port

    def Connect(self):  # Connect with server
        self.sock_client.connect((self.IpAddr,self.port))
        self.sock_client.settimeout(5)

    def Close(self):  # Close connection with server
        self.GoWork=False
        self.sock_client.close();

    def Start_Exch(self): # This method start exchange with server. Send start exchange command,
        self.sock_client.send(b'start') #send start command
        print ("I'm send data")
        result_str="1111"
        try:
            data = self.sock_client.recv(2048) #recive data form server
        except:
            pass
        else:
            byte_arr_data = bytearray(data)
            data_count = byte_arr_data[1]*256+byte_arr_data[0] #convert byte[0,1] to int
            i=2
            tmp_byte_arr = bytearray(data_count)
            while i<data_count+2:

                tmp_byte_arr[i-2] = byte_arr_data[i]
                i+=1

                result_str = tmp_byte_arr.decode('utf-8')
            if result_str == 'Started':
                print(result_str)
                self.GoWork = True
                self.getDataServer()
            else:
                self.GoWork = False



    def getDataServer(self): # this method recive data from server work in thread
        while self.GoWork:
            self.sock_client.send(b'send')  # Send message to starting
            try:
                data = self.sock_client.recv(2048) #recive data form server
            except:
                pass
            else:
                byte_arr_data = bytearray(data)
                data_count = byte_arr_data[1] * 256 + byte_arr_data[0]  # convert byte[0,1] to int
                i = 2
                tmp_byte_arr = bytearray(data_count)
                while i < data_count + 2:
                    tmp_byte_arr[i - 2] = byte_arr_data[i]
                    i += 1
                    result_str = tmp_byte_arr.decode('utf-8')
                print (result_str)
```

И собственно сам вызов

```
client = Client('127.0.0.1', 8080)
client.Connect()
client.Start_Exch()
```

В функции `Start_Exch()` происходит запуск функции `getDataServer()` которая постоянно опрашивает сервер. Однако естественно, что весь код, который идет после `client.Start_Exch()` не выполняется, потому что код в `getDataServer()` по сути выполняется в бесконечном цикле. Подскажите, как мне организовать программу, чтобы я мог периодический отправлять запрос серверу и получать от него данные, а после этого что то с ними делать, т.е. чтобы скрипт работал по такой схеме

`getDataServer()` *(данные получены)* -> `Foo()` *(делаем что то с данными)* -> *снова запускаем* `getDataServer()`

Comment: Смотрите в сторону многозадачности/многопоточности.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Прием сообщений в socket python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/684398/204271)